# How does RunLoop reduces CPU cycles

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrunloop

I have been reading about `RunLoops` for a few days in Apple documentation and stuff from Google search. I have understood the concept of `RunLoops` to great extent but still I got no answer to some basic questions regarding `RunLoops`.

1. How `Runloop` exactly works ? Is it something like while loop running at some system level ?
2. If it is indeed some sort of while loop at some system level, then how does it differ from polling ?

Please provide me with some pointers for this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point about a RunLoop (variously named as Window Handler, main-loop, event-loop on other platforms) is that it facilitates an *Event Driven Architecture* in which an application only runs when there is something to do - for example, responding to user-interaction.   This is the opposite of polling.

Fundamental to the architecture is a some kind of message queue that a thread can block on until a message available for processing.  On MacOSX and iOS systems the queue is a [Mach kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_%28kernel%29) RPC `port`.  On Windows it's a kernel IPC queue, and X-windows systems, a unix-domain or network socket.

Events are inserted into the queue by other system components - for instance a Window Manager and other applications.  It is also common for applications to message themselves from other threads in order to perform all UI processing in the same thread.

The run-loop itself resides in application space and looks something like this:

```
while (!stop)
{
    message = WaitForNextMessage();
    DispatchMessage(message);
}
```

Usually, whatever UI framework you use provides a mechanism for registering an event handler for particular types of events.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Your answer has indeed cleared my concept of RunLoops. But I think I need to dig further down and read about what you mentioned in your answer Event Driven Architecture.